# If a nilpotent group $A$ act on a group $G$ then $G$ is solvable.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups

**Theorem:** If a nilpotent group $A$ act on $G$ by automorphism and $C_G(A)=e$ then $G$ is solvable.

I hope that the statement of theorem is true. It should belong to Hartley, but when I googled it I could not find the the theorem.

If someone provides the whole statement of the theorem with source, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $A$ is a subgroup of ${\rm Aut(G)}$ with $C_G(A)=1$, then one says that $G$ acts *fixed-point-freely* upon $G$ by automorphisms.

The *fixed-point-free automorphism conjecture* asserts that if a finite group $G$ admits a fixed-point-free automorphism group $A$ (and, if $A$ is noncyclic, further suppose that $gcd(|G|, |A|) = 1$), then G is soluble.

Several special cases are known, e.g., see the article [Solubility of finite groups admitting a fixed-point-free automorphism of order $rst$](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102736596) by Peter Rowley.

The **nilpotent** case has been proved quite recently in the article [Nilpotent fixed-point-free automorphism groups and regular abelian Carter subgroups](http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/pdf/1305.6263v1.pdf) by Jabara and Spiga:

**Theorem (Jabara, Spiga 2013):** Let $G$ be a finite group and let $A$ be a nilpotent group acting on $G$ as a group of automorphisms with $C_G(A) = 1$. Then $G$ is soluble.